# Monitoring Java from within Java

Tags: java, monitoring, visualization, monitor

I want to write a simple visualization of a Java program by displaying the program's method calls as branches of a tree. This could be done quite simply by having the program itself tell the visualization what it is doing, but I want to be able to do this with any Java method/class and not just the ones I modify to do so.

What I need is the ability to watch the methods a program calls and what methods are called within that method and so on. Obviously, stack traces provide exactly this functionality:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException
     at MyClass.mash(MyClass.java:9)
     at MyClass.crunch(MyClass.java:6)
     at MyClass.main(MyClass.java:3)
```

So I thought about having the program I want to monitor run in a thread and then just look at that thread's stack. However, the thread class does not really support this. It only supports *printing* the current stack.

Now I, of course, thought of simply changing the PrintStream of the System class so the thread would print its stack into *my* PrintStream, but this feels kind of wrong.

Is there a better way to do this? Are there any pre-existing classes/methods I can use?

Also, I'm currently downloading the Java source code, to check how exactly the thread class prints its stack so I could maybe subclass thread and imitate the dumpStack() method with my own getStack() method.

Comment: I know it 'feels wrong' but it's not - one can re-direct System.out ( to a PrintStream which writes to a file ) I ended up writing my own Console, previously I have done things like this enough times by now to know that all this is in libs, be it in java.util or whatever: If you can get a dumpStack() anywhere, dump it to where-ever you want: That's what it's for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh shoot, looking through the source code I noticed the thread class has a method public StackTraceElement[] getStackTrace(), it just wasn't in the documentation I was reading. Now I feel dumb.

So yeah, that seems to be the solution.

Comment: THis is a "newer" addition.  You might have been looking at Java 1.4 javadoc.

Answer (score 2):

Look also at VisualVM, shipped with latest Java releases.

Comment: You can also add your own custom plugins to this framework without too much trouble.

Answer (score 0):

One approach might be to use something like [BCEL](http://jakarta.apache.org/bcel/) to preprocess the target bytecode to insert calls to your own code on every method entry and exit (probably best to do exit by wrapping the whole method in a try/finally block, to catch exception exits). From this, you can deduce the call tree exactly as it happens.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/) for that. Have a look at this [description](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/starting-development.html#tracing) of exactly your use case.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [ThreadMXBean](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/profiling/profiling_java5_threads_howto.shtml) class -- it my provide what you need. Essentially, you:

- call ManagementFactory.getThreadMXBean() to get an instance of ThreadMXBean;
- call getAllThreadIds() on the resulting ThreadMXBean to enumerate current threads;
- call getThreadInfo() to get the top n stack trace elements from a given list of threads.